# Visual/Text Editor displays blank pages in WP-Admin- but HTML on client side displays correctly

Tags: mysql, editor, formatting, xml

Theme: Hemingway, Twenty-Sixteen
Host: Bluehost
Browser(s): Safari, Chrome
OS: OSX El Capitan 10.10.5 (14F1605)
[Website](http://harmonywv.com/wordpress/)

**When I try to "Edit Page" visual editor screen is blank, in both Text and Visual.**

This is a x-post from Wordpress.com where I have gotten no response.  Have tried for many hours to get assistance from bluehost tech support, but they have not been helpful.

Site was uploaded to remote host from local install, after a lot of workarounds. It seemed that there were multiple installations of Wordpress populating the cpanel, and after initial install, with various blank pages and "database connection error"s I got a functioning front end by trying these steps-

Uninstalled all versions of Wordpress
Deleted Php and MySQL DB's associated with installs
Deleted orphaned files left from uninstall
Reinstalled. updated mySQL, PHP, and wp-config files.

This got my site accessible at both /wordpress and /wordpress/wp-admin

But when I try to "Edit Page" visual editor screen is blank, in both Text and Visual.

So far I have:
Deactivated Plugins
Changed Theme
Cleared Browser History and Cache
 deleted wp-includes and wp-admin folders and reinstalled from a fresh installation. I then deleted wp-content folder and uploaded again from local installation.

I turned off/reset/on cache on cpanel cache.

I checked charSet in myPHP- UTF8

> added to wp-config.php
>   define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
>
> /*That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */'
>
> 'define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );

before I ran the debugger and I got a few "unexpected CSS token"

### n one page- for the post.php file

[Warning] Unexpected CSS token: : (mediaelementplayer.min.css, line 1)

### filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr=#323232, endColorstr=#000000);

using Debug Bar I see:
WARNING: wp-includes/formatting.php:3297 - htmlspecialchars() [function.htmlspecialchars]: Invalid multibyte sequence in argument
include('wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php'), wp_editor, _WP_Editors::editor, apply_filters('the_editor_content'), call_user_func_array, format_for_editor, htmlspecialchars

Text/HTML can be added to existing pages, which overwrites page.

using Debug Bar I still when on focus in edit window I still see:
WARNING: wp-includes/formatting.php:3297 - htmlspecialchars() [function.htmlspecialchars]: Invalid multibyte sequence in argument
include('wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php'), wp_editor, _WP_Editors::editor, apply_filters('the_editor_content'), call_user_func_array, format_for_editor, htmlspecialchars
which looks like this:
[image: Screenshot from WP-Admin using Debug Bar]

Wondering if I did the find and replace correctly on .xml prior to uploading. Should all localhost references be replaced with http://"WebAdress.com"?  I did a find and replace, but it seems like some are still there.  I assumed that these were for internal navigation on the server using localhost as root.

It seems like the easiest way to resolve this problem is to uninstall WP and all associated files and then just to start again from scratch, but when I attempt this it seems like I must be leaving some associated files behind.

What are steps/best practices for clearing server of associated files?
What is the best link for uploading a local install to remote server. ---they seemed to have different methods which seems like that caused my issues

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Not sure where to start. It seems that you are did something bad while migrating the site and you have end up with a big mess. Try to remove WordPress totally from you hosting. Then try to do the migration again following the instructions in [Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress). Or, if you feel more confortable, any of the several plugins that make the migration a few clicks operation, [search the repository](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=migration).